# Django allauth url fetch from react calls signup view form. How can I just send the data to the API endpoint?

Tags: django, reactjs, api, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I am using React as a standalone SPA connecting to a Django backend with allauth to manage authentication. Typing in the URL on my local browser (192.168.86.28:8000/accounts/signup/ or 127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/), brings me to a form I can populate with my custom fields. I can enter in the information and it completes the signup correctly in my database.  (See Picture 1).

The form looks ugly, however, so I would like to implement my own frontend form using react. A fetch call with the data should simply post it to the database, but instead the fetch call to that URL brings up the form! How can I change this so the URL will instead send the data to my database?

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url
from allauth.account.views import confirm_email
from allauth.account.views import SignupView


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('accounts/signup/', SignupView.as_view(), name="account_signup"),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

mysite/settings.py

```
# rest_framework authentications and permissions
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSS': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ]
}

# cors

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://192.168.86.28:3000',
    'http://192.168.86.33:3000',
)

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]',
    "192.168.86.33", "192.168.86.28",
]

# authentication

SITE_ID = 1

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer',
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_EMAIL_ENTER_TWICE = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = '/?verification=1'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = '/?verification=1'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "http://192.168.86.28:3000/"
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "http://192.168.86.28:3000/"
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    "signup": "users.forms.CustomSignupForm",
}

ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "users.adapter.CustomAccountAdapter"
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
from allauth.account.utils import setup_user_email

from rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer

# serializes the fields in /rest-auth/registration/ form


class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=25)
    is_teacher = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    is_student = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    is_admin = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    is_parent = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    is_visitor = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        data_dict = super().get_cleaned_data()
        data_dict['first_name'] = self.validated_data.get('first_name', '')
        data_dict['last_name'] = self.validated_data.get('last_name', '')
        data_dict['is_teacher'] = self.validated_data.get('is_teacher', '')
        data_dict['is_student'] = self.validated_data.get('is_student', '')
        data_dict['is_admin'] = self.validated_data.get('is_admin', '')
        data_dict['is_parent'] = self.validated_data.get('is_parent', '')
        data_dict['is_visitor'] = self.validated_data.get('is_visitor', '')

        return data_dict
```

forms.py

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from django import forms

class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    # using forms.field to show widget
    # I will have to remove this and pass the fields for JSON React API
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=25, label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=25, label='Last Name')
    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        return user
```

adapters.py

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter


class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=False):
        user = super().save_user(request, user, form, commit)
        data = form.cleaned_data
        user.first_name = data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = data.get('last_name')
        user.is_teacher = data.get('is_teacher')
        user.is_student = data.get('is_student')
        user.is_admin = data.get('is_admin')
        user.is_parent = data.get('is_parent')
        user.is_visitor = data.get('is_visitor')

        user.save()
        return user
```

react form handler (.js)

```
handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const csrftoken = Cookies.get("csrftoken");
      const teacher_registration_url = url_prefix + "/accounts/signup/";
      console.log(csrftoken);
      try {
        fetch(teacher_registration_url, {
          credentials: "include",
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "x-csrftoken": csrftoken,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        })
        // .then(response => response.json())
        // .then(response => {
          // console.log(response);
        // });
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
```

[I can enter data into this custom form and successfully signup a user.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3MR0.png)

[How can I do the same thing from my React onSubmit handler? As you can see it calls the form instead of sending the data straight to the database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LDVd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I updated my API call in JS to call rest-auth's API endpoint instead of all-auth's account registration form, and that solved the problem. Leaving this up here in case it can help someone else in the future.

(Instead of fetching "accounts/registration/" which leads to all-auth's very handy registration form, changing the fetch to "rest-auth/registration" sends the information directly to the database.)